# Modificar DropDownList MVC usando Usuarios?

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio, mvc

Tengo estos modelos en mi proyecto usuarios, febriles, distritos y servicios, en usuarios y febriles se requiere los datos de distritos y servicios, tengo un dropdownlist con el siguiente script jquery y json:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#DistrictId").change(function () {
           $("#ServiceId").empty();
           $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: '@Url.Action("GetServices")',
               dataType: 'json',
               data: { districtId: $("#DistrictId").val() },
               success: function (districts) {
                   $.each(districts, function (i, service) {
                       $("#ServiceId").append('<option value="'
                           + service.ServiceId + '">'
                           + service.Name + '</option>');
                   });
               },
               error: function (ex) {
                   alert('Failed to retrieve services.' + ex);
               }
           });
           return false;
       })
   });
</script>
```

En el controlador de febriles tengo este metodo para obtener los servicios del jquery:

```
  public JsonResult GetServices(int districtId)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var services = db.Services.Where(s => s.DistrictId == districtId).OrderBy(s => s.Name);
        return Json(services);
    }
```

Y en mi vista create de febriles tengo esto:

```
@model Fevers.Models.Fever

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Fever</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DistrictId, "District", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("DistrictId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DistrictId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ServiceId, "Service", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ServiceId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ServiceId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuantityPatients, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuantityPatients, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuantityPatients, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuantityFevers, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuantityFevers, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuantityFevers, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
<div>
  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Lo que deseo hacer es que despues de ingresar un usuario y este se loguee se cargue unicamente los servicios del distrito al que pertenece dicho usuario.

Answer (score 2):

Si vas a usar `$.ajax` no se usa el `@Html.DropDownList` ya que no enviarias los datos como parte del modelo sino que lo recuperas usando ajax y json

```
<select id="ServiceId" class="form-control"> 
</select>
```

con solo definir el html alcanza para que luego cuando se ejecute el $.ajax y definas los options

Quizas un punto importante es la carga del combo en el load de la pagina si es que el combo `District` tiene una opcion por defecto

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(function () {

       $("#DistrictId").change(function () {
           LoadService();
       })

       LoadService();
   });

   function LoadService(){
        $("#ServiceId").empty();
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '@Url.Action("GetServices")',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: { districtId: $("#DistrictId").val() },
           success: function (districts) {
               $.each(districts, function (i, service) {
                   $("#ServiceId").append('<option value="'
                       + service.ServiceId + '">'
                       + service.Name + '</option>');
               });
           },
           error: function (ex) {
               alert('Failed to retrieve services.' + ex);
           }
        });
   }
</script>
```

Comment: edite la respuesta y agregue un detalle que podria interesar

Comment: Cambiare el `@Html.DropDownList` por `<select id="ServiceId" class="form-control"> 
</select>` en mi vista. Gracias @LeandroTuttini.

Answer (score 1):

Si tu pregunta es; 
Lo que deseo hacer es que despues de ingresar un usuario y este se loguee se cargue unicamente los servicios del distrito al que pertenece dicho usuario.

La respuesta es la siguente:

Primero: Debes hacer una relacion entre las tablas de tu BaseDatos y las tablas del IdentityUser especificamente la tabla ApplicationUser. La idea es que cuando el usuario despues de hacer login con una consulta de esta forma

```
var estaAutentificado = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; // verifica si esta autentificado el usaurio, devuelde un Boolean
if (estaAutentificado)
{
 var idUsuario = User.Identity.GetUserId(); // Obtiene el id del usuario
}
```

Segundo: debes hacer un consulta  en tu metodo GetServices, parecido este, usando la propiedades de navegacion:

```
var services = db.Users.Where(x => x.Id == idUsuario ).Include(x => x.Services).ToList();
```

Si tienes alguna duda, puedes pregunta,.
Gracias!!

Comment: Gracias Antonio, podrias ayudarme con el script perdona es que javascript no es lo mio, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: seguro escribeme  a mi e-mail desarrollador@unicoc.edu.co